# odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, pgadmin, openerp

recientemente me encuentro utilizando odoo 12 en Visual Studio 2017 para Windows 10, donde también hice una solución en python. La instalación fue del todo bien, sin embargo, cuando intento iniciar la solución con el depurador me aparece esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la configuración del archivo **odoo.conf**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al principio creí que era cuestión de permisos dentro del archivo pg_hba.conf de postgres, así que agregué los permisos correspondientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esto tampoco funcionó. **¿Alguien podría ayudarme?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si sea demasiado tarde para responder.

Veo que en el archivo odoo.conf en esta linea:

db_host = False

Debieras de colocar:

**db_host = localhost**

o la URL del servidor o pc donde tengas alojada la base de datos, ejemplo:

db_host = 192.168.x.x

Y también si al momento de crear la base de datos agregaste algún usuario entonces debes colocarlo aqui:

**db_password = la_contraseña**

Saludos.

Comment: Efectivamente, me hacía falta colocar el **puerto** & el **host**, muchas gracias!